# How to make two image button hyperlinks side-by-side take up full screen?

Tags: html, css, image, css-float, css-position

I want to have two images, left and right halves of the page, that when clicked, re-direct to a particular link.

When the user enters the webpage, I want them to see nothing but these two images (which are clickable), and I don't want it to be scrollable either, i.e. I just want it to fit on the single page.

Not very experienced with HTML - how to modify/rewrite the code below?

```
<a href="http://www.google.com">
<img src="left_image.png" alt="Go to Google!" >
</a>

<a href="http://www.facebook.com">
<img src="right_image.png" alt="Go to Facebook!" >
</a>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking something like this

```css
html,body{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  margin:0
}
div.container{
  position:relative;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  
}
.left, .right{
    width:50%;
    height:inherit;
    float:left
}
a{
  display:block;
  width:100%;
  height:inherit
}
.left{
  background:url(http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/desktop-year-of-the-tiger-images-wallpaper.jpg);
  background-size:cover;
}
.right{
  background:url(https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2016/03/28/12/35/cat-1285634_960_720.png);
  background-size:cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    <a href="www.google.com" ></a>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
      <a href="www.facebook.com"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Silly question, but can all of this code go in the main html file?

Comment: Yes, you can. But make sure the container div is appended as a direct child to the body tag

Answer (score 2):

The best method I think would be to use a `flexbox` with `viewport units` (`vh` and `vw`) and use a `backround-image` with `background-size: cover` - see demo below:

```css
body{
  margin:0;
  display:flex;
}
*{
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
a {
  width:50vw;
  height: 100vh;
  border:1px solid red;
  display:flex;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}
a.left{
  background-image: url('http://placehold.it/500x500');
}
a.right{
  background-image: url('http://placehold.it/600x600');
}
```

```html
<a class="left" href="http://www.google.com"></a>
<a class="right" href="http://www.facebook.com"></a>
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a lot of answers to this so just choose what you like. This is how to work with it in general no matter what goes in the div.

```css
.holder {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.one, .two {
    width: 50%;
}
.one {
    background: red;
}
.two {
    background: green;
}
```

```html
    <div class="holder">
    <div class="one"><a href="http://www.google.com">
    <img src="left_image.png" alt="Go to Google!" >
    </a>
    </div>
    <div class="two"><a href="http://www.facebook.com">
    <img src="right_image.png" alt="Go to Facebook!" >
    </a></div>
    </div>
```